# Single column matrix and its transpose to create Symmetric matrix in python, numpy scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there any existing function in numpy or scipy to do following operation?

```
z = [a, b]
z*z.T (transpose of the z)
=
[[a**2, a*b]
[b*a, b**2]]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use numpy [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function:

```
np.outer([2,4],[2,4])
array([[ 4,  8],
       [ 8, 16]])
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the standard function I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a function per se, but this will give you what you want:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([3,4])
z[:,np.newaxis]*z[np.newaxis,:]

# Returns:
# [[ 9 12]
#  [12 16]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It works!  the standard function, I was looking for is outer function as mentioned by @yeharav . certainly good to have another alternative!

Comment: `z.T` doesn't change anything if `z` is 1d.  I think you want: `z[:,np.newaxis]*z[np.newaxis,:]`  (the 2nd `newaxis` (`None`) is optional, but I included it for clarity).